# OSError [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I'm trying to run a python script with

```
response = session.get('https://0.0.0.0/api/client', verify=False)

print(response)
```

Every time I run the script, I get OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context. I don't understand why. I tried using the same API on Postman and it was able to run. Is there something wrong with the code???

Answer (score 1):

You can not connect to *0.0.0.0* because it is not an valid IP address. If you configured your server to listen on *0.0.0.0* (listen on every available network interface) you should be able to just use *127.0.0.1* or *localhost*.

Try this example (You should use http instead of https with localhost):

```
response = session.get('http://127.0.0.1/api/client', verify=False)

print(response)
```

You can find more information on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0).

Comment: I tried using the code that you recommended me with localhost, but I'm getting the same error.